# Regular expression to match sets of numbers that are not equal nor reversed

Tags: regex

I am referring as a follow up on this question here: [Regular expression to match two numbers that are not equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257685/regular-expression-to-match-two-numbers-that-are-not-equal)

Now my other question scenario is this:

```
P121324 - T  
P1212 - F - we got this covered in the message on link above (no same "sets")
P1221 - F - now new restriction - not even the reversed digits 12 - 21
```

But, the problem now is that the P string can be very long! - like this:

```
P121315162324
```

please notice this is ok since the "sets" are:

```
12 13 14 15 16 23 24
```

Now, I could make this in the code (PHP) by checking if there are repetitions, but I was wondering if this can be done with single regex command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
^P(?:([0-9])(?!\1)([0-9])(?!(?:..)*(?:\1\2|\2\1)))*$
```

If you want the digits to be restricted to [1-6] like in your previous question then change [0-9] to [1-6].

See it working online: [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/AGlyBYW9KW)

---

Here is a breakdown of the regular expression:

```
^          Start of string/line.
P          Literal P
(?:<snip>) Non-capturing group that matches a distinct pair of digits. See below.
*          Zero or more pairs (use + if you want to require at least one pair).
$          End of string/line.
```

Explanation of `([0-9])(?!\1)([0-9])(?!(?:..)*(?:\1\2|\2\1))` - match one pair:

```
([0-9])    Match and capture the first digit. Later refered to as \1.
(?!\1)     Negative lookahead. The next character must not be the same as \1.
([0-9])    Match and capture a digit. Later refered to as \2.
(?!<snip>) Negative lookahead. Check that the pair doesn't occur again.
```

Explanation of `(?:..)*(?:\1\2|\2\1)` - try to find the same pair again:

```
(?:..)*       Match any number of pairs.
(?:\1\2|\2\1) Match either \1\2 or \2\1.
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is working very well! Can I please ask to explain me how it works?
WOW, and thanx for rubular!

Comment: Thank you, this was a great learning experience. Would upvote you like 100 times!