# Get pairs of digit from string with regexp

Tags: regex

I found similar question [Regular expression to match sets of numbers that are not equal nor reversed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258471/regular-expression-to-match-sets-of-numbers-that-are-not-equal-nor-reversed) but I'm bad in regexp so need an advice.
I have string, i.e: 3344654865 and I need to know that first characters are two not equal pairs.
I tried this regexp

```
^(?:(\d)(?:\1)(\d)(?:\2))
```

but it captures only first digit in pair

```
1.  [0-1]   `3`
2.  [2-3]   `4`
```

In example 3344654865 it should capture two pairs of digit, where digits inside pair are equal 3=3, and 4=4.
How to upgrade my regexp that it will return two not equal pairs from the begining of the string ?

Comment: what is your desired output for this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^((\d)\2)(?!\1)((\d)\4)
```

Result:

```
3344654865 -> (33, 3, 44, 4)
12345      -> fail (digits not same in pairs)
9          -> fail (too short)
3333       -> fail (two pairs same)
```

It is hard to eliminate the intervening groups of one character since they're needed for backreferences.

Comment: It does work, saying that it is not a match (33 -> fail, 34 -> 34, 345 -> 34), according to your specification ("I need to know that first characters are two not equal pairs"). Otherwise I don't understand your question; please specify the desired input and desired output.

Comment: Input: 3344654865
Desired output:3344
Sorry for my bad explanation

Comment: What would be the output for input 3737? How about for 12345? What about 9?

Comment: In example with 3737 it should be skiped. I try to get pairs where first and second digit equals, i.e 55, 77, etc.

Comment: Why not answer the question fully? Is `12345` valid or not? Should the digits in pairs be same (like `33`, `44`) or is it just a coincidence in your case, since it is nowhere listed explicitly, except in your code sample that you state doesn't work? I assume yes, but for the future, you need to write several cases for regexp matches, to cover all the situations, not only the ideal one you are thinking about.

Comment: Sorry, 12345 is not valid, yes - digits in pairs should be same. I'm new in regexp, so don't know how to give descriptive examples.

Comment: I don't understand, I posted the same exact pattern 19 minutes ago and did not get the check mark !!!??

Comment: @alphabravo: Yeah, it does appear your update is the same as my code. Which means you must be a mind reader! :) (since I was at that time still trying to get the correct requirements.) However, I'm not, so can't answer why OP accepted mine and not yours. The best I can do is just give you a +1 for a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me `^((\d)\2)(?!\1)(\d)\3.*`
matches first characters are two not equal pairs
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mO3tY4)

Update: per request `^((\d)\2)(?!\1)((\d)\4)` desired match are no. 1 & 3
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mP0gX1)

if matches have to be 1 & 2 then use one of previous patterns to verify it meets your criteria then apply this pattern `^(\d\d)(\d\d)`

Comment: Oh, is it possible that it'll return 
1.`33`
2.`44`
instead of
1.`33`
2.`3`
3.`4`
?

Comment: `^((\d)\2)(?!\1)((\d)\4)` use match #1 & 3

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
^(\d+?)(?!\1)(\d+)
```

will give you:

```
 33 - 44654865
```

it is not trivial to make the second part of the same length, but the first digits of the second part are guaranteed to be not the same as the first one. So you will have to get them yourself.

By not trivial, I mean you need to try 1 digit, 2 digits, 3 digits, and so on with alternation or a loop.